# Updating and saving pinned ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm using Parse to save an object to the local datastore:

```
ParseObject product = new ParseObject("Product");
product.put("title", "Product A");
product.put("available", false);
product.pinInBackground();
```

Later I'm updating some properties:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Product");
query.fromLocalDatastore();
query.whereEqualTo("name","Product A");    
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> productList, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      for (ParseObject product: productList) {
        product.put("available", true);
        // [A]: call product.pinInBackGround() again?
      }
    } else {
      // something went wrong
    }
  }
});
```

Now I would like to have these changes stored to the local datastore. Is this done automatically, or do I have to call `pinInBackground` again (see [A])? The [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-retrieving-objects-from-the-local-datastore) isn't very clear on this (ie. what does `save` mean?):

> Whenever you save changes to the object, or fetch new changes from
>   Parse, the copy in the datastore will be automatically updated, so you
>   don't have to worry about it.

Note that I don't sync over the network, i.e. `saveEventually` or `saveInBackground` are never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no need to pin object again.

And you can test it by fetching this object from local data store.